# IngressNginx Kubernetes disable/remove finalizers

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I install ingress in the standard way. Using the Helm Chart.
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx

But I do not want my LoadBalancer to be automatically deleted when the controller is deleted.

```
   finalizers:
     - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
```

This value is set by default to the service during installation. And I don't see how it can be removed/configured.
I don't understand why it's set like this by default. After all, this is not practical, if LoadBalancer is deleted, then when creating a new one, it will be assigned a different IP, which means that DNS will need to be redirected to another IP.

And a second question if I may. How do I configure Service to automatically update LoadBalancer status? When the service connects to it, everything is fine, but when I remove the LoadBalancer, the service continues to be in an active state.
I use Hetzner. Annotation `load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/health-check-interval: 15` does not work in the service.
Available annotations can be viewed here: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hetznercloud/hcloud-cloud-controller-manager/internal/annotation)

Answer (score 1):

**You can remove finalizers by two ways:**

1. Using `kubectl edit svc service_name`, remove the part below and save it again.

`finalizers:`

```
` - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup`
```

2. You can use [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) to update objects in place.

   `kubectl patch ingress $Ingressname -n $namespace -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":[]}}' --type=merge`

As per this [Doc](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/05/14/using-finalizers-to-control-deletion/#owner-references) you can try to delete the ingress controller without deleting the load balancer using `kubectl delete --cascade=orphan` , [cascade](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/use-cascading-deletion/#set-orphan-deletion-policy) option is used when you want to delete the owner object but the orphan will not get deleted . Can you try this and let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work. I mean, it's not a solution. If I set the finalizers to null, then some backend process returns the previous value. And I do not know what and where to set it up. This is my question.

Comment: Edited my answer check it if this helps.

Comment: Hi Sai. With `--cascade=orphan` i an interesting option. I should try it. But I mean not Ingress resource. I mean Service of type Loadbalancer.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. But as an idea, I find it very interesting and one that might work.